# Magento 2.3.2 Upgrade from 2.2.2

Tags: configurable-product, magento-upgrade, magento2.3.2

We have recently upgraded from Magento 2.2.2 to 2.3.2.
And we having an issue in layered filter navigation.

**Issue:**

When we filter size M for the configurable product (Size M is out of stock).
So behaves correctly and does not show the product(configurable) in listing as per default Magento configuration 'Do not show out of stock product'. Which works correctly.

Now we are filtering next, where we need size M and Color Red product. At that time that out of stock product appears

***Expected result*:** it does not have to appear.

***Actual result*:** It appears still it is out of stock.

What I felt is, when we filter multi attributes. (Size: M, Color:Red) It comes with the wrong result but when filter single attribute (Size: M), It works perfectly.

Any clue why this happens?

Highly appreciated if someone helps out.

Answer (score 0):

Run `php bin/magento indexer:reindex`

**Flush the cache and check**

**Hope this will work for you**

Comment: Not luck with that, tried setup:upgrade, reinde, deployment, cache clear, everthing...

Comment: Did you check the setting for color attribute?

Comment: Check if is there any error in console.

Comment: What kind of setting, it shows on filter (filter with result). So setting seems for i think... Any other setting?

Comment: Yes filterable with result, use in listing etc

Comment: Yes, everything was correct. It happens in the 2.3.2 version which we upgraded. In the last version of 2.2.2, it was working correctly.

Comment: Need proper elaboration of the issue to get a solution? Can you provide a console screenshot? If any error in post request

Comment: No issue in syste,.log, exception.log or any other log. no log registered on this. Everything works smooth.   but not getting expected result. Please read question one more time.

Comment: Is there any third party extension installed for layered navigation?

Comment: installed but removed all external modules and themes still not working.

Comment: Can you provide link to check the issue?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96855/discussion-between-mitali-and-padhiyar-gaurang).

Comment: Did you get any solution?

Comment: yes, for magento core code we have developed code, but for amasty we are still working on it